# How to scale rectangle with rounded corners laterally but keep round corners intact?

Tags: inkscape

I want to make a rectangle wider but keep its vertical size and rounded corners. How can I do that without affecting the roundness of corners?

I am using Inkscape 0.92.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *Edit > Preferences > Behaviour > Transforms*, deselect the "scale rounded corners in rectangles" option. You can also disable the "scale stroke width" option.  You can also access these options in the controls bar along the top, when you have the Select and Transform tool selected.

Now when you scale the rectangle the corners won't scale.

[image]

Another method is to first convert the rectangle to paths using *Path > Object to Path*, then you can select the nodes on one side of the rectangle using the Edit Paths by Nodes tool, and move them with the arrow keys, or hold down Ctrl as you click and drag one of the select nodes to constrain the angle.

[image]

**Edit**: Further to the comments below, it would seem that there may have been a small glitch when the OP created the rectangle which prevented the OP from using the methods described above. Creating a new rounded rectangle seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: Neither of those work for me. The corners are still stretched after following your instructions in the first one. If I try to convert the object to path it says "no objects to convert to path in the selection". I'll post pictures

Comment: @user153397 How did you make the rectangle? This only works for rectangles you made in Inkscape. It won't work on raster objects you have imported.

Comment: Pictures:https://i.imgur.com/Jf9X6i1.png and https://i.imgur.com/WWIVBz9.png. I made the rectangle in inkscape with the rectangle tool, 5th button from top. Then added rounded corners with the 2nd button.

Comment: Sorry, tried to add a line change with enter but instead the message was posted. I added images and more explanations.

Comment: Draw a rectangle and round the corners using the round rectangle control. [Watch this](https://imgur.com/Ah49GIB).

Comment: Ok, the rounded corners are now kept intact with the new rectangle. What's wrong with the old one? I'm 100% I did it the  exactly same way.

Comment: @user153397 - I have no idea, maybe a little glitch? Anyway glad you got it fixed.

Comment: I'll accept your answer if you add the bit about just making a new rectangle as that it was what fixed the issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user153397 done.